# How can I make a minefield with dr racket?

Tags: c++

Can you give me code if some knows code?it is too important for me

Comment: DrRacket is an IDE for the Racket/Scheme programming languages, why do you have C++ in the title?
What do you mean by 'make a minefield'?

Comment: Possibly does mean to make say "minecraft"?

Comment: Or a minesweeper clone? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the completely right idea by starting with something simple. However, minesweeper is a trivial program for most developers - you might try something even simpler. Maybe even start with programming something other than a game - maybe "Hello World" or such.

Try something even simpler, maybe a [text adventure](http://www.textadventures.co.uk/quest/). This might give you the mind-set you need to make a minesweeper.

*Off topic:* People on any StackExchange website (StackOverflow included) don't take kindly *at all* to people asking for 'code'. Demonstrate your due diligence to us, and come with specific problems and we will be more than happy to help you out with any problems - but asking for an entire program will be met with a closed question and sometimes some hostility.